# Webpack -p doesn't create bundle correctly

Tags: reactjs, build, webpack

I started learning React by myself and I decided to create a boilerplate for me. I'm getting a problem to build a project using webpack. When I run in dev mode, works fine. When I run the command 'postinstall' to build for production, it generates a bundle.js with only a few bytes. But when I run the 'postinstall' without the parameter -p, it generates my bundle with ~ 2MB, the same thing when generates for dev mode (obviously because is not set for production). I didn't figure out why the production flag isn't creating my bundle correct. Can someone help me with this problem?

The project is in the repository:
https://github.com/ribeiroguilherme/react-boilerplate-dashboard

The webpack.production.config.js file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CleanPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');


const plugins = [
  new CleanPlugin('dist'),
  new ExtractPlugin('bundle.css'),
  new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true }),
  new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
    },
  }),
];

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  debug: false,
  context: __dirname + '/src/client',
  entry: {
    javascript: './index.jsx',
    html: './index.html',
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/client'),
  },
  eslint: {
    configFile: './.eslintrc',
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
      },
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader'),
      },

    ],
  },
  plugins: plugins,
};
```

I'm also worried because the bundle looks pretty big for a project that I just started now. Any hints will be very appreciated.

Best Regards

Comment: First thing I notice is you should use `dev-tool: source-map` and not eval.

Comment: I sorted out the problem. I just changed the approach to move the HTML to the /dist folder, using html-webpack-plugin.